# "p: datatable" selection

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I am using a `p:datatable` and selection to handle in my bean the selected record. This works. But I want to preset a selected row when initializing the datatable. Is this possible? How?

Now it doesn't preset a record, even though selectedCompany is set. Is it because I do it before the return to jsf has been made?

This is the code I have

Bean

```
public Map<String, Object> getSelectedCompany() {
    return selectedCompany;
}

public void setSelectedCompany(Map<String, Object> selectedCompany) {
    this.selectedCompany = selectedCompany;
}
public MWSGenericMapList getHandlingCompanies() {

    if (companyItems == null) {
companyItems = retrieveHandlingCompanyItems(partnerIds);
            for (int i = 0; i < companyItems.size(); i++) {
                if (companyItems.get(i).get("businesspartnerid").equals(getnewCustomerPartnerId())) {
                    setSelectedCompany(companyItems.get(i));
                }
            }
}
return companyItems;
}
```

Jsf

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="ptable100" id="handlingCompanies" var="company" value="#{switchCompany.handlingCompanies}" width="100%" height="200" 
        emptyMessage="#{msg.all_lists_no_records_found}" paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,50,100"
        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}  #{msg.all_lists_numberOfRowsDisplayed_label} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        selection="#{switchCompany.selectedCompany}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{company.businesspartnerid}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@form" listener="#{switchCompany.handleCompanyChange}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, the selected row did get set, I was just not on the first page (too many rows to display on 1 page) so I missed it. But it works the way I did it.